# converting sessions in hibernate to plein JDBC connections

Tags: java, hibernate, session, jdbc

I am shifting back from hibernate to plain JDBC in order to overcome the overheads incurred in using hibernate.I wanted to know how to deal with the sessions associated with hibernate.How should i convert back to Plain JDBC so that all my sessions are replaced with the JDBC connections.And please let me know if I am wrong in my thoughts that replacing a session with a connection converts back to plain JDBC as I am not well versed in these concepts and dont know if i am going in the right way.

Comment: What about the queries? Are you using HQL or Criteria API? You also have to convert all your queries.

Comment: Yes i have converted all queries.I have replaced all HQLs with SQL

Answer (score 3):

I have used Hibernate extensively in high-performance tasks, including batch insertion of millions of records. Your problem is not with Hibernate, but with the way you are using it.

Above all, do not use Hibernate as a persistent state manager; use it as a thin layer above the raw SQL and you won't complain about performance.

1. Always prefer `StatelessSession` (it works for everything you need except `save` operations)`;
2. never use lazy fetching, use explicit joins for everythng;
3. never fetch whole objects, use SELECT to fetch exactly what you need;
4. fetch as much as possible in a single statement, avoid n+1 selects at all costs;
5. for large result sets, never use `list`, use `iterate` or `scroll`.

The list goes on, but this is what I have come up with at this moment.

As far as your direct question, it depends on the application. If it is a Spring application, then you will certainly want to use its declarative transaction management. Basically, you just put a few lines of XML config and you'll have an open DataSource in your DAO code ready to be used, with no management on your part.

If you are doing something more raw, then by all means use a connection pool library, such as the great BoneCP. You acquire connections from it and later return them to it, again with no explicit management.

Lastly, if you really want a bare-bones, unsafe and non-scalable approach, then you can create connections directly from the JDBC driver. This approach is really only for schoolwork and it is not recommended even in the smallest of production-worthy projects.

Comment: Thanks Marko for the reply,but I am a beginner in the corporate world and its my TL's decision to convert back to plain JDBC. My database is not huge and it does not keep changing so that Hibernate or other ORMs are opted.I have almost replaced all the HQLs with SQLs and stuck with the sessions now.Please help.

Answer (score 1):

A Hibernate session is much more than a JDBC connection. It contains multiple such connections (usually managed via a JDBC Connection Pool which recycles JDBC Connection instances), a bunch of entities which are attached to, and managed by said session and other things as well (caching, etc).

Removing Hibernate and doing everything with the JDBC API-only will imply more than just replacing Hibernate Session instances with one or more JDBC connections followed by a duplication of the Hibernate code into analogous JDBC API calls. If you'd only do that, you'd simply do a lot of work for nothing, as you'd lose all of Hibernate's advantages (less verbose code, a higher level of abstraction, etc) and gain nothing of JDBC's advantages (less heap memory used, fewer method calls (yes, even with Hibernate's Javassist magic, this still counts towards performance in some cases), finer grained control of the database interactions, etc).

My advice is to first really look into the problems your app has (apparently due to Hibernate) and at least for the major ones, try to first see if you can't do something to optimize it without getting rid of Hibernate. Yes, Hibernate can become heavy and memory hungry, but more often than not, the issue with performance comes from improper use of the framework (are you sure you're fetching all the necessary associated entities in one query, or do you make Hibernate make hidden joins or pseudo joins in the background? Are you doing or you data operations on the database side, or is some of that done in Java code after a more-than-necessarily-generic Hibernate query is executed to fetch the data? etc.)

If you really need to get rid of Hibernate (maybe you need to use some very specific features of your database which are not standard SQL and which Hibernate doesn't let you access, like MySQL's ability to import big amounts of data via a custom flat-file format) then make sure that what ever it is you're replacing it with (plain JDBC, or maybe some other ORM like EclipseLink) can tackle the issue and solve it in a more performant way. Doing a small POC to test these before you start re hauling your code can save you a ton of time.

Answer (score 0):

While I strongly urge you to heed the advice of Marko and Shivan,  you could use hibernate to manage your connections/sessions/transactions  and to execute your SQL queries without much overhead being generated.

a quick google search yielded this on executing SQL from a hibernate session.

http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=java&seqNum=575

While I agree with both of the earlier answers, if you truly want to go down the road of executing straight SQL, I would look into this option for two reasons.

1) your sessions are already in place.  If you don't have hibernate load up all of your entities I don't see how hibernate would generate that much overhead.

2)If the problem is speed,  and not overhead which I have run into before, you can implement this to quickly execute native SQL in your problem areas and keep all of hibernates ORM goodies in place.

All of that being said, I would also urge you to dig into the documentation for hibernate.  I have used hibernate for several high performance solutions with great success.   While the nuances can be hard to grapple with in the beginning, the benefits of using hibernate (or at least something that adheres to JPA standard) far outweigh the cost of not doing so down the road scalability wise.